# Avoiding to search for the appropriate type in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

in order adapt some code I find myself looking for the appropriate type in my python code. Is there a way to avoid this or do this faster?

Consider the following code for example:

```
def my_function(my_list)
   for my_entry in [entry for entry in my list if ...]
```

my_entry in this case is a namedTuple, but I have to look where my_function is used and look up the "invocation"-chain in order to know that **my_list** is a list of namedTuples. Is there a better solution? I am used to statically typed languages.

Just to make it clear, I am not necessary looking for **type hints**, but for good solution.

Comment: For one, better variable naming helps. Secondly, you can use [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) for type hints

Comment: Type hinting helps make python look more like static language and a good Autocompleter (e.g. jedi) would be sufficient for the 80% of cases. However, just like in any dynamic language it's often necessary that you should just put a breakpoint there (e.g. IPython, pudb) and introspect the live objects.

Comment: The simplest solution is to document the parameters when writing the code... FWIW a good naming scheme can often be enough as documentation.